# Network taking about a minute to initialise - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

When I load my computer up, my initializing network symbol appears on my network icon for about a minute.

When this happens I can 1) Ping google.com 2) Connect to VoIP software and speak to people.

I can't however Open Mozilla (it doesn't even load until the network has decided its connected) and this happens with Steam and a couple of other programs.

I have no idea where to start tracking this down because I obviously have an internet connection because I can ping google and speak on VoIP software when it happens.

Comment: What kind of network are you attached to?

Comment: Its just my computer plugged into my Sky Netgear router.

Answer (score 0):

I would try assign your self a static IP address and also statically set the DNS resolver in your network adaptor settings, just to rule out anything there.

Comment: I have already tried assigning a static IP and DNS. I can't turn the DHCP off on my router though so not sure if that is messing something up.

Answer (score 0):

Well I decided to actually sit down and get to the bottom of this. I looked in MSCONFIG / Services whilst the network was initialising and noticed the `Debug Diagnostic Service` was "Pending Start". After disabling this service my network now connects immediately.